# How to create ConcurrentMultiMap

Tags: java, multithreading, multimap

I am trying to create cache based on concurrent MultiMap
with good performance:
key - String,
value - List.
This cache should serve for 2 operations:

1. put()
2. entrySet()
3. clear()

There are a lot of threads can get access to my cache. I've googled and find this maybe good solution:

```
public class Cache<K, V> {

    private final ConcurrentMap<K, List<V>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public List<V> get(K k) {
        List<V> list = cache.get(k);
        return list == null ? new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>() : list;
    }

    public void put(K k, V v) {
        List<V> list = cache.get(k);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
            List<V> oldList = cache.putIfAbsent(k, list);
            if (oldList != null) {
                list = oldList;
            }
        }
        list.add(v);
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<K, List<V>>> entrySet() {
        return cache.entrySet();
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

but I am not sure if this solution really works, could somebody help me???
 Especially I am wondering if it works when two parallel threads:
 1. first is trying to put some element
 2. second is trying to clear all

What happened in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case you mention, this class works.  However, there are a lot of other problems with the class.  In particular, there can be a race condition between two `put()` calls with the same key, and the `get()` operation exposes the actual lists in the underlying map, which unlimited access by unsynchronized code.

Comment: I share list just for read, there are not modifying operations. But I see that it's not safe, if somebody put data to list